# Gluster Not Syncing Even Though Volume Is Created

Tags: ubuntu, replication, glusterfs

I have installed Gluster on two ubuntu boxes on my LAN.  Everyting appears fine but when I write a file to the folder on server1 it does not appear in the folder on server 2.  Here are the only two tests I know of to test if the volume is working.  I have tested that the peers connect and they do.

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www# netstat -tap | grep glusterfsd
tcp        0      0 *:49152                 *:*                     LISTEN      11637/glusterfsd
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.2:49152      192.168.10.2:1023       ESTABLISHED 11637/glusterfsd
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.2:1022       192.168.10.2:24007      ESTABLISHED 11637/glusterfsd
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.2:49152      192.168.10.3:1014       ESTABLISHED 11637/glusterfsd
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.2:49152      192.168.10.3:1020       ESTABLISHED 11637/glusterfsd
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.2:49152      192.168.10.2:1020       ESTABLISHED 11637/glusterfsd

root@ubuntu:/var/www# gluster volume info

Volume Name: kdevvol
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 9170886e-2d95-43fb-9425-514f142cb38a
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: 192.168.10.2:/var/www
Brick2: 192.168.10.3:/var/www
```

I get the same results on both servers.

Answer (score 6):

How do you carry out the write?

Have you mounted the volume in server 1 and write some file at mounted location. (and then mount the volume in server 2 and write some file at mounted location).

You should be writing in that way to see the desired result.
DO NOT directly write on the bricks in server1 and server2 and expect it to work. It should be over the volume to see the replication work.

Answer (score 4):

Gluster server syncs the volume only when a write comes from a client. If you want to have a replication within the servers, you would need to mount the volume in each of the server. 
However, I don't think it's a good idea as too much work for the servers and let the clients feed the servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the servers to mount the volume. Typically, you would do this from an external machine, known as a "client". Since using this method would require additional packages to be installed on the client machine, For sake of testing (or if server is act as computing/storage), Follow below steps

```
mount -t glusterfs server1:/kdevvol /mnt
```

Then you can see synched data.